# How would one do minv3.1 in pinescript?

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v5

In TC2000 its possible to use minv3.1 (minimum volume requirement for each of the last 3 bars) which I cannot figure out for pinescript (since its not the same a average volume). How would one create it?

I've only tried

V[0] > 1000 **and** V[1] > 1000 **and** V[2] > 1000

But I'm not sure if that's even correct or the best approach.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `ta.lowest()` function returns the lowest value for a given number of bars back. You can use this to check the lowest value of `volume` and then compare it to 1000:

```
minVolume = ta.lowest(volume, 3)
condition = minVolume > 1000
```

Answer (score 0):

You are not so far , you should use the volume function (from pinescript) and try :

```
minimum_vol_requirement = 1000
if volume[2] > minimum_vol_requirement
    if volume[1] > minimum_vol_requirement
        if volume > minimum_vol_requirement
            // here all your conditions are ok
```